# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering, isomorphic-javascript

I’m working on an Isomorphic react application using redux and I'm getting a promise error even this exact same code is working on previous modules.
Here i'm fetching data through fetchMobile action and through that i'm updating store data.
And loaddata function used to run dunction on server.

```
class MobilesList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMobiles();
  }
...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 // console.log(state); //i can get data in state
  return { mobile: state.mobile };
}

function loadData(store,id) {
  return store.dispatch(fetchMobiles());
}

export default {
  loadData,
  component: connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchMobiles,fetchMobilesPage })(MobilesList)
};
```

---

Error i'm getting are :

```
*Error-1 : The above error occurred in the <MobilesList> component:
    in MobilesList (created by Connect(MobilesList))
    in Connect(MobilesList) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App (created by Route)
    in Route
    in Switch
    in div
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in Provider

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
You can learn more about error boundaries

Error-2 : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
    at bundle.js:41672
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MobilesList.renderPosts (bundle.js:41659)
    at MobilesList.render (bundle.js:41716)
    at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:27178)
    at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:27155)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:27534)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:29502)
    at workLoop (bundle.js:29611)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback*
```

---

renderPost function

```
renderPosts() {
    return this.props.mobile.map(single => {
      return   <div key={single.postId} className={"container"}><Link to={"/"+single.postSlug} slug={single.postSlug}>
      <div class="card" >
          <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <img class="activator" src={single.featuredImage.sizes.medium.file)}/>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{single.postTitle}</span>

          </div>
        </div>
        </Link>
        </div> ;

  });
  }
```

Comment: Please share `renderPosts ` of your `MobileList` component

Comment: i have updated in question please check

Comment: Thank you ... Did you bind your `renderPosts` function in your constructor ? ... if yes ... try to `console.log`  `single.featuredImage.sizes.medium` inside your `map` function ... cause most likely you have one record that has `medium = undefined`

Comment: yes ,i didn't check api data for this request ,thanks :)